# Passing string with colon Oracle SELECT

Tags: c#, oracle

i want to use statement like this:

```
SELECT TABLENAME_SEQ.nextval FROM DUAL
```

and it returns good value (eg 7, number), but when i use:
`SELECT :something FROM DUAL`, and in something pass (as a string in C#) TABLENAME_SEQ.nextval,
 i got return:
TABLENAME_SEQ.nextval in column named :something.

My code looks like:

```
string statement = "SELECT :seqName FROM DUAL";
OracleParameter[] parameters = new OracleParameter[] {
new OracleParameter("seqName", seqName + ".nextval")
};
```

So, how to pass that value? Any value? Same results when i pass * or anything.

Comment: Please post your code as well.

Comment: What is `:something` ? Please post your C# code.

Comment: the colon prefix indicates a parameter. string parameters are literals and never evaluated as expressions or PL/SQL functions (which would defy their purpose). so what you are trying cannot be done except with dynamic execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with binding variable but you can use template engine as Velocity to transform such operation as:

```
templateMap.put("something", "TABLENAME_SEQ.nextval");
```

template file:

```
SELECT $something FROM DUAL
```